# Cassandra column metadata shows "DateType" instead of "timestamp" after driver upgrade

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-java-driver

I have some Java code that performs introspection on the schema of Cassandra tables.  After upgrading the Cassandra driver dependency, this code is no longer working as expected.  With the old driver version, the type for a `timestamp` column was returned from [`ColumnMetadata#getType()`](http://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java-dse/1.3/com/datastax/driver/core/ColumnMetadata.html#getType--) as  [`DataType.Name#TIMESTAMP`](http://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java-dse/1.3/com/datastax/driver/core/DataType.Name.html#TIMESTAMP).  With the new driver, the same call returns [`DataType.Name#CUSTOM`](http://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java-dse/1.3/com/datastax/driver/core/DataType.Name.html#CUSTOM) and [`CustomType#getCustomTypeClassName`](http://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java-dse/1.3/com/datastax/driver/core/DataType.CustomType.html#getCustomTypeClassName--) returning `org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.DateType`.

The old driver version is `com.datastax.cassandra:cassandra-driver-core:2.1.9`:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
    <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.9</version>
</dependency>
```

The new driver version is `com.datastax.cassandra:dse-driver:1.1.2`:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
    <artifactId>dse-driver</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

The cluster version is DataStax Enterprise 2.1.11.969:

```
cqlsh> SELECT release_version FROM system.local;

 release_version
-----------------
      2.1.11.969
```

To illustrate the problem, I created a simple console application that prints column metadata for a specified table.  (See below.)  When built with the old driver, the output looks like this:

```
# old driver
mvn -Pcassandra-driver clean package
java -jar target/cassandra-print-column-metadata-cassandra-driver.jar <address> <user> <password> <keyspace> <table>
...
ts timestamp
...
```

When built with the new driver, the output looks like this:

```
# new driver
mvn -Pdse-driver clean package
java -jar target/cassandra-print-column-metadata-dse-driver.jar <address> <user> <password> <keyspace> <table>
...
ts 'org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.DateType'
...
```

So far, I have only encountered this problem with `timestamp` columns.  I have not seen it for any other data types, though my schema does not exhaustively use all of the supported data types.

`DESCRIBE TABLE` shows that the column is `timestamp`.  `system.schema_columns` shows that the `validator` is `org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.DateType`.

```
[cqlsh 3.1.7 | Cassandra 2.1.11.969 | CQL spec 3.0.0 | Thrift protocol 19.39.0]

cqlsh:my_keyspace> DESCRIBE TABLE my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table (
  prim_addr text,
  ch text,
  received_on timestamp,
  ...
  PRIMARY KEY (prim_addr, ch, received_on)
) WITH
  bloom_filter_fp_chance=0.100000 AND
  caching='{"keys":"ALL", "rows_per_partition":"NONE"}' AND
  comment='emm_ks' AND
  dclocal_read_repair_chance=0.000000 AND
  gc_grace_seconds=864000 AND
  read_repair_chance=0.100000 AND
  compaction={'sstable_size_in_mb': '160', 'class': 'LeveledCompactionStrategy'} AND
  compression={'sstable_compression': 'SnappyCompressor'};

cqlsh:system> SELECT * FROM system.schema_columns WHERE keyspace_name = 'my_keyspace' AND columnfamily_name = 'my_table' AND column_name IN ('prim_addr', 'ch', 'received_on');

 keyspace_name | columnfamily_name | column_name | component_index | index_name | index_options | index_type | type           | validator
---------------+-------------------+-------------+-----------------+------------+---------------+------------+----------------+------------------------------------------
     my_keyspace |  my_table |          ch |               0 |       null |          null |       null | clustering_key | org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type
     my_keyspace |  my_table |   prim_addr |            null |       null |          null |       null |  partition_key | org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type
     my_keyspace |  my_table | received_on |               1 |       null |          null |       null | clustering_key | org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.DateType
```

Is this a bug in the driver, an intentional change in behavior, or some kind of misconfiguration on my part?

### pom.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>cnauroth</groupId>
    <artifactId>cassandra-print-column-metadata</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <description>Console application that prints Cassandra table column metadata</description>
    <name>cassandra-print-column-metadata</name>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
        <slf4j.version>1.7.25</slf4j.version>
    </properties> 

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                            <mainClass>cnauroth.Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
                    <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>dse-driver</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
                    <artifactId>dse-driver</artifactId>
                    <version>1.1.2</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <finalName>${project.artifactId}-dse-driver</finalName>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>cassandra-driver</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
                    <version>2.1.9</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <finalName>${project.artifactId}-cassandra-driver</finalName>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

### Main.java

```java
package cnauroth;

import java.util.List;

import com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster;
import com.datastax.driver.core.ColumnMetadata;
import com.datastax.driver.core.Session;

class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // Skipping validation for brevity
        String address = args[0];
        String user = args[1];
        String password = args[2];
        String keyspace = args[3];
        String table = args[4];

        try (Cluster cluster = new Cluster.Builder()
                .addContactPoints(address)
                .withCredentials(user, password)
                .build()) {
            List<ColumnMetadata> columns =
                    cluster.getMetadata().getKeyspace(keyspace).getTable(table).getColumns();
            for (ColumnMetadata column : columns) {
                System.out.println(column);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: could you share the 'describe table' output for the table that has a column show this behavior?  I would not expect this unless the column was created with the full class name.  There was some schema parsing changes between 2.x and 3.x (dse driver 1.x) that may be causing this, but it shouldn't happen if the column was created with 'timestamp' as the type instead of the full class name.

Comment: @AndyTolbert , thanks for your reply.  I have updated the question with `cqlsh` output that shows more of the schema information.

Comment: I see, I didn't notice that there are two implementations of the cql timestamp type in cassandra 'org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.DateType' and 'org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.TimestampType'.  Apparently 'DateType' was replaced in 2.0 (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-5723).  I'll add a more detailed answer

Comment: Good idea to include the system.schema_columns output, that was really helpful in isolating the issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the internal Cassandra type used for Timestamp changed from `org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.DateType` and `org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.TimestampType` between Cassandra 1.2 and 2.0 ([CASSANDRA-5723](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-5723)).  If you created the table with Cassandra 1.2 (or a DSE compatible version) `DateType` would be used (even if you upgraded your cluster later).

It appears that the 2.1 version of the java driver was able to account for this ([source](https://github.com/datastax/java-driver/blob/2.1/driver-core/src/main/java/com/datastax/driver/core/CassandraTypeParser.java#L64-L65)) but starting with 3.0 it does not ([source](https://github.com/datastax/java-driver/blob/3.3.0/driver-core/src/main/java/com/datastax/driver/core/DataTypeClassNameParser.java#L66)).  Instead, it parses it as a Custom type.

Fortunately, the driver is still able to serialize and deserialize this column as the cql timestamp type is communicated over the protocol in responses, but it's a bug that the driver parses this as the wrong type.   I went ahead and created [JAVA-1561](https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/JAVA-1561) to track this.

If you were to migrate your cluster to C* 3.0+ or DSE 5.0+ I suspect the problem goes away as the schema tables reference the cql name instead of the representative Java class name (unless it is indeed a custom type).

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  I have enough information now to work around the bug until it gets fixed or we upgrade the cluster.